# Is the link for a marginal trend in a logistic model the logit?

Tags: logistic, trend, marginal-effect

Exactly as in the title. If I estimate marginal trends for a logistic model, are these expressed as a log odds ratio? How does one express that in a way that makes intuitive sense? Change in odds ratio per time unit is a bit awkward.